# I am trying to give Project Creator role to a service account from IAM in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am trying to give Project Creator role to a service account from IAM, I do not see a role named Project Creator as explained here https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resource-manager-roles

[I am not getting Project creator as a role in Service Account Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K215U.png)

Comment: You cannot assign Project Creator at the project level. In the Google Cloud Console, select your organization while in the Resource Manager page. Then you can assign this permission. The permission must be assigned at the level which will be the parent of any new projects.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the answer. I was actually looking in to get organization level role exposure and just then after reading your comment and digging more docs i found that i need to associate my cloud identity account to see organization level roles. I am in to that process now. I am just getting started with gcp iam.

Comment: If you have a Pluralsight subscription, watch this course: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/google-cloud-platform-iam-regulating-resource/table-of-contents

Comment: For YouTube, watch this session: https://youtu.be/tNG4RUpBUso

Comment: To add to my comment "The permission must be `assigned` or `inherited` at the level  which will be the parent of any new projects"

Comment: What i am still missing is ability to add Service account and Project Creator Role on Org/Folder level, I am able to give Project Creator role to Individual User Account on Org or Folder level but Service account is grey out (What i am getting it is Project level resoruce), so i am still not able to add a service account with Project Creator role. Is it even possible to have a SA on org/folder level ? In the mean while I am going through pluralsight course as well, thanks for the link and all the suggestions.

Comment: Have you seen any evidence anywhere that a service account CAN have permissions to create projects?  It may simply be that a project can ONLY be associated with a real user account.

Comment: That's what I see in gcp, but let's relate with some infrastructure architecture perspective of another cloud, project in gcp is pretty what we call resource group in azure. You can have a service principal (service account in gcp) to create resource group and use IAM to define a user boundary to deploy resources in that resource group. Now from a practical example in gcp, I have seen qwiklabs create projects on demand, does it create using a user context? Or how it does because that is what I want to achieve in self service model

Answer (score 4):

Its `roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator` and lowest resource hierarchy where it can be given is `Folder`. So if you have a Folder then create an IAM role at Folder level(you need to have permissions at Folder level) or else create at Org level(again, you need to have org level perms).

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resource-manager-roles

````
roles/
resourcemanager.projectCreator  Project Creator     Provides access to create new projects. Once a user creates a project, they're automatically granted the owner role for that project.   resourcemanager.organizations.get
resourcemanager.projects.create
    Folder ```


Hope this helps
````

Answer (score 2):

If you do not see the project creator role in IAM, you will have to contact the Organization admin who should have the ability to add that particular role.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than think of giving a user/service account permissions "globally", think about giving those permissions contextually.  Imagine a user with the identity of `user@gmail.com`.  You want that user to be able to create projects ... but it isn't as simple as that.  Within GCP, you have the concept of folders which can contain projects.  If I have two folders `folder1` and `folder2`, and I want to the user to be able to create projects in `folder1` but not `folder2`, we seem to have a problem.  If I said that the user could *just* create projects, that would be too broad.

The better way to think about it is that there is a hierarchy of resources ... these start at the root (the organization) and then we have folders beneath that (optionally) and we end up with projects.   Now we have enough to complete the story.

What GCP allows us to do is state:

At this level (organization or folder) I wish to give this user this permission.  This then propagates downwards from that tree level but does not propagate horizontally.

And thus we get to the root of your question.  When you go to IAM, you are trying to associate roles to a user "globally" as opposed to "contextually".  There is no concept of giving a user project create globally ... instead you give it contextually either at an organization or folder level.  Note that if you assign a permission at the organization level, that is effectively global as everything nests down from the organization.

Comment: Right, i also dont want any user account to give this role but rather give it to a service account and use it to automate project creation project. The problem here i see is the role is available above project level in hierarchy but SA seems not to be available above project level to assign this role.

Answer (score 1):

As John Hanley mentioned before it should be done under organization level. I have attache a photo.

[Resource manager > Project creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YeIO.png)

Comment: Yes i am getting this now on org/folder level for user accounts but i do not see a way for doing this for a Service Account on org/folder level.

Comment: First search for your service account then at organization level  assign "Resource manager > Project creator" role to it.

Comment: Thank you so much @Pejvak !! initially it was giving some error while i was adding SA from IAM but now i am able to add and deploy resources using the key for SA.

Comment: How did you get this to work? I can't seem to find a way to give that permission to a service account

Comment: That role is not available for in the GUI for me :thinking-face: (project deleter and mover is there, but not creator)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your Service Account at Project Level;
2. Copy the email of your Service Account;
3. Go to your Organization and *Add a new principal* to it with the role *Project Creator* and use the copied email taken in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can create org/folder with Project Creator role, and then grant this role to a Service Account in a project under this org/folder.
To do it using the console:

- Create a Service Account in a project that is under the org/folder
- Go to the "Manage resources" page and select the org/folder
- On the Info panel on the right under Permissions, enter the Service Account email address
- In the select role drop down, select Resource Manager > Project Creator